# Call REST API calls to transfer zip files using MQ is feasible?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, message-queue, mq

We need to send zip files which is created in my local centralized server to a particular shop's server using MQ and spring boot.*

Local server is a centralized server and many shops servers (More than 5000+).
We'll build zip files for each store separately from the centralized server and we will connect to each shop's server using REST call to transfer the zip files.
(Ex:- for 10 shops, we'll create 10 different zip files which contains necessary independent information of each shops and transfer).

can we do the file transfer using a queue system (MQ)?

if so, how to call REST APIs from a queue. or kindly suggest some idea to do this or any different approach

Comment: Q: Doesn't MQ have a message limit (e.g. 4MB)?  Would that be a limitation for you?

Comment: could you please suggest any alternative solution?. Or any different approach

Comment: MQ message limit is 100MB. MQ MFT will break up files into smaller chunks to send over MQ. Are you asking to use MQ MFT over REST or are you asking about writing your own file transfer program using MQ's REST interface. Why do you need to use REST?

Comment: @Roney Francis: it's unclear what your "requirements" are.  Is REST a requirement?  Is MQ? Or is this an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?  ANYWAY: 1) MQ per se has a definitely message limit.  This may or may not be a problem for you.  2) [MQ Message File Transfer](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=overview-how-does-mft-work-mq) may or may not help.  Typically, your Spring Boot app will interact with MQ; it might also provide a REST interface.  Here's a good example: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-jms-application-development-with-spring-boot/.

Comment: @paulsm4, we're trying to call file transfer REST API from the queue. . We understood, its not possible. 
we're checking feasibility of the queue frameworks in our  application.
could do u please suggest any idea to transfer zip files through a queue framework or any similar kind of technology?

Just need to get an idea.. If need to send files in a queue managed system. how to achieve this?

Comment: See @MoragHughson' s comment above for a IBM product, Google the product mentioned if not known.   Also check out the open source [UFM](https://www.capitalware.com/ufm_overview.html) from Capitalware.

Comment: Thank u @JoshMc ,@MoragHughson  and All . i will try that way